# SQL, PHP - adding a constraint to a drop down function

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

SQL, PHP question about adding a constraint to an add function.

I have a parent table *dogs* and a child table *health record*

dogs

```
==================================
id | name | breed | gender | dob |
==================================
```

id = primary key

healthRecord

```
====================================
id | fluVax | allergies |  memberFK
====================================
```

memberFK is UNIQUE and is the forign key that points to dogs.id

The code only allows one health record, per dog. A one-to-one relationship.

This bit of code inserts the data fine

```
if(!($stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO healthRecord(fluVax, allergies, 
memberfk) VALUES (?,?,?)")))
{
    echo "Prepare failed: "  . $stmt->errno . " " . $stmt->error;
}
}
if(!($stmt->bind_param("ssi",$_POST['fluVax'],$_POST['allergies'], 
$_POST['memberId'])))
```

But I'm sure this is the code I need to edit

```
<p> Dog's Name: <select name="dogId">
<?php
    foreach($dogs as $dog)
    {
        echo "<option value='" . $dog["id"] . "'>" . $dog["name"] . " 
</option>";
    }
?>

    <p>Flu Vax: <input type='date' name='fluVax'/></p>
    <p>Conditions: <input type='text' name='conditions'></p>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

This produces a drop down of all the dogs in the database, and I want to alter the drop down to just show dogs that don't already have one so there will only be one record per dog. Because healthRecord.memberfk is set to UNIQUE, if the user tries to add a record for a dog that already has one an error is correctly returned. But what I want is a drop down that allows the user to only select dogs that don't have an existing record

Comment: "but ONLY for dogs that don't have one existing" - does that mean you never have more than one health_record for a dog record? If so, your foreign key is in the wrong table.

Answer (score 1):

Its a bit hard to understand your problem... but I'll try ;)

So if i understood you, there is only 1 healthRecord for each dog. 
So first of all, you should make healthRecord.memberfk UNIQUE. To avoid double entries.

Second: You should make an SELECT of dogs (maybe with a JOIN on healthRecord) to get the dogs with health data to print the select (or insert data) in the way you need it and only the data you need.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to say that the healthRecord.memberfk is set to UNIQUE.  If someone tries to add a record for a dog that already has one an error is returned.  I will try to create a SELECT statement like you say that only populates the drop down with dogs that don't have an existing fk in the table